# finding the data === true from an array returning from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I want to check `is_reqestor = true` while returning from the find() of mongoose. But while updating the same doc i am passing `id` but it has to update the data.

```
let filter = {
                is_reqestor: true
             }

  if (!isAdd) {
                filter["_id"] = { "$ne": id };
              }

    userModel.find(filter, function (err, docs) {
                    if (docs.filter(el => console.log(el.is_requestor)).length > 1 || docs.length >= 1 && userObj.is_active === true) {
                        result.error = "Requestor already exists: " + userObj.is_reqestor;
                        console.log("`Requestor already exists", null);
                        let resp = api_respose.getSuccessResponse(process.env.WEB_URI, result);
                        resolve(resp);
                    }
```

in `docs` I am getting the data from mongo which comes under array and I have to check in that data `is_reqestor = true` then console.log("Reqester exists")

this is data I'm getting on console.log of `docs` after find()

````
[ { email: 'esample@example.com',
  job_title: '',
  _id: "9374938749",
  department: 'Credit',
  company_heading: 'Example',
  suite: '',
  city: 'D',
  state: 'CA',
  is_reqestor: true,
  is_active: true,
  name: 'Joe doe',
  role: '343434',
  legacy_id: '1323',
  __v: 0 },
  { email: 'd@example.com',
  job_title: '',
  _id: "93744338749",
  department: 'Credit',
  company_heading: 'Example',
  suite: '',
  city: 'D',
  state: 'CA',
  is_reqestor: false,
  is_active: true,
  name: 'Joe doe',
  role: '343434',
  legacy_id: '1323',
  __v: 0 },
  { email: 'd@example.com',
  job_title: '',
  _id: "93743438749",
  department: 'Credit',
  company_heading: 'Example',
  suite: '',
  city: 'D',
  state: 'CA',
  is_reqestor: true,
  is_active: false,
  name: 'Joe doe',
  role: '343434',
  legacy_id: '1323',
  __v: 0 } ]```
````

Comment: Why not add the `is_reqestor: true` to the filter?

Comment: added that but while adding data putting `is_reqestor" : false` it throws  Requestor already exists

Answer (score 0):

I may be confused by the question but if all you're looking to do is filter out the objects that have `is_requestor: false` a filter function should work.

Something like:

```
docs.filter(el => el.is_requestor)
```

will return the objects where `is_requestor: true`.  If I'm missing the point leave me a comment and I'll see if I can come up with something else.

Comment: if (docs.length >= 1)  with this adding new with is_reqester = false says it exists

and with this condition 
if (docs.length > 1)  than at update time it says it let `is_reqester` = true

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow - what exactly are you trying to do? If you're looking for any objects where is_requestor is true you can run the code above.  You can check the length of the resulting array to log that the requestor exists.

Comment: Adding your code says `undefined` check updated question

Comment: if all u want to do is enter the block of the if statement if any of the objects contain `is_requestor: true` use this check: `if (docs.filter(el => console.log(el.is_requestor)).length) { // do whatever`